# How do I get my keyboard back

Tags: keyboard

I just got a new tablet a few days ago & today I disabled a lot of apps that I knew I wasn't going to use. When I put it down 2 go eat dinner & came back, I turned it back on & when I tapped the little box to put my password in the keyboard didn't pop up. I reset it about 20 times but nothing happened. What do I do now?

Comment: What kind of reset you have used?

Comment: Also what method did you use to disable apps?

Comment: @MANI: He probably means reboot

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Use/get a USB OTG cable and plug a USB keyboard in to type the password. After that it's a matter of finding the likely disabled keyboard app or installing a new one from the store ie op2.

You may be able to jigger up a bluetooth keyboard also if the pairing popup overrides the lock (likely not but can't say for sure myself).

Option 2:

This is assuming you can get around the lock issue which is unlikely but I figure I throw it out there in case its helpful to someone else in a similar situation that isn't blocked by a lock.

You should be able to use https://play.google.com/store?hl=en to install a keyboard remotely like: [Swiftkey Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey&hl=en) or [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en).

After it installs on your device, run it from the notification tray and go through the prompts/settings to enable it. At the very least you now have a backup keyboard to use to find and re-enable the presumably disabled one.

Option 3:

This requires root and a good deal more knowledge of your system and also depends on whatever method you used (unmentioned as of writing) to disable the apps in the first place.

Get an adb shell going and get a directory listing of `/data/app` &| `/system/app` &| `/system/priv-app` and reverse the disabling process manually.

Option 4:

Do a full Factory Data Reset from recovery.

Typically Power+Vol Down held down to get into the bootloader and then launch the recovery from there. May vary by device (unmentioned as of writing).